# Code is printing only the first index item in the list but not the rest

Tags: python

I have this web application that will allow a user to enter a Input id to get information for. For example:

```
Input: x632
```

Output would be like:

```
Comp Unique ID: x123 Label of Page: Apple Name of Comp: Fruit

Comp Unique ID: x456 Label of Page: Water Name of Comp: Environment

Comp Unique ID: x789 Label of Page: Shirt Name of Comp: Clothing
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <ol>
        {%for i in result%}
        <li>{{i}}</li>
        {%endfor%}
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Python Code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import datetime
import os
import csv
import re
import glob

app = Flask(__name__)

temp_storage = {}
    def myFunction(COMP, source="."):
        list_output = []
        for pathway in glob.glob(os.pathway.join(source,"x*.xml")):
            document = temp_storage.setdefault(pathway, ET.parse(pathway).getroot())
            theLocationPoint = document.findall('.//*[@Comp="' + COMP + '"]')
            if theLocationPoint:
                comp_unique_id = document.get("ID")
                comp_label = document.tag
                comp_name = document.get("Name")
                myFunction(comp_unique_id, source=source) 
                list_output.append("Comp Unique ID: " + comp_unique_id + " " + "Label of Page: " + comp_label + " " + "Name of Comp: " + comp_name)
                myFunction(comp_unique_id, source=source)
        return list_output
            

# Creating a route that has both GET and POST request methods
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form.get('name')
        #calling myFunction
        return_string = myFunction(name, source=r"C:/Sam/XMLContentFiles/")
        return render_template('my-form.html', result=return_string)
    return render_template('my-form.html', result='')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**Question:** The problem I am running into with this code is that this code prints only the first index of the `list_output` to the web page.

For example if I input

```
input: x632
```

The Output is:

`Comp Unique ID: x123 Label of Page: Apple Name of Comp: Fruit`

But the output should actually be:

```
Comp Unique ID: x123 Label of Page: Apple Name of Comp: Fruit

Comp Unique ID: x456 Label of Page: Water Name of Comp: Environment

Comp Unique ID: x789 Label of Page: Shirt Name of Comp: Clothing
```

Why is the code printing only the first index in the list? Is it not being `appended` properly? Is it ignoring the `myFunction()` recursive call? I am thinking there is something wrong with these lines of code but I am exactly sure why:

```
list_output.append("Comp Unique ID: " + comp_unique_id + " " + "Label of Page: " + comp_label + " " + "Name of Comp: " + comp_name)
myFunction(comp_unique_id, source=source)
```

Comment: what happens to a function when you execute the line with `return`? Hint: add a for loop in the template

Comment: fix your indentation

Comment: copy/paste the code you posted and your editor should mark the problem

Comment: don't return a string, but a list of tuples/objects, you can't manipulate/format the string in the template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the value before finishing the entire iteration. That is why it is printing only first iteration value.
I would suggest you to collect your iteration output in a list and return the list once iteration is over.

```
def myFunction(COMP, source="."):
        
      lst_output = []   
      for pathway in glob.glob(os.pathway.join(source,"x*.xml")):
        document = temp_storage.setdefault(pathway, ET.parse(pathway).getroot())
        theLocationPoint = document.findall('.//*[@Comp="' + COMP + '"]')
        if theLocationPoint:
            comp_unique_id = document.get("ID")
            comp_label = document.tag
            comp_name = document.get("Name")
            myFunction(comp_unique_id, source=source)
            **lst_output.append**("Comp Unique ID: " + comp_unique_id + " " + "Label of Page: " + comp_label + " " + "Name of Comp: " + comp_name)
      return lst_output
```

Or you will have to put iteration in the template.

Comment: I tried your suggested code but it's  still printing only the first iteration value. How can I put iteration in the template?

Comment: Did you change your template with for condition? You need to iterate the result list... 
{% for r in result %}
    {{ r }}
{% endfor %}

Comment: Yes, I did that but it still just print the first iteration.

Comment: I was able resolve the issue. I had to declare the lst_output = [] outside of the function(like a global variable).